# Model not firing parse function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I'm having a problem where my backbone model isn't parsing something correctly. Here is the listing.js:

```
SpendYourSavings.Models.Listing = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "api/listings/",
    images: function() {
        this._images = this._images || new SpendYourSavings.Collections.Images([], { listing: this });
        return this._images;
    },
    reviews: function() {
        this._reviews = this._reviews || new SpendYourSavings.Collections.Reviews([], { listing: this });
        return this._reviews;
    },
    shop: function() {
        this._shop = this._shop || new SpendYourSavings.Models.Shop([], { listing: this });
        return this._shop;
    },


    parse: function(data) {
        if(data.images) {
            this.images().set(data.images, { parse: true });
            delete data.images;
        }
        if(data.reviews) {
            this.reviews().set(data.reviews, { parse: true });
            delete data.reviews;
        }
        if(data.shop) {
            this.shop().set(data.shop, { parse: true });
            delete data.shop;
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```

Images and reviews work, but shop doesn't quite work. It sets the attributes of shop correctly, but it doesn't set the image properly.

Here is the shop.js:

```
SpendYourSavings.Models.Shop = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/api/shops",

    reviews: function() {
        this._reviews = this._reviews || new SpendYourSavings.Collections.Reviews([], {});
        return this._reviews;
    },

    listings: function() {
        this._listings = this._listings || new SpendYourSavings.Collections.Listings([], {});
        return this._listings;
    },

    user: function() {
        this._user = this._user || new SpendYourSavings.Models.User([], {});
        return this._user;
    },

    image: function() {
        this._image = this._image || new SpendYourSavings.Models.Image([], {});
        return this._image
    },

    parse: function(data) {
        console.log("shop parse data: " + data);
        debugger
        if(data.listings) {
            this.listings().set(data.listings, { parse: true });
            delete data.listings;
        }
        if(data.reviews) {
            this.reviews().set(data.reviews, { parse: true });
            delete data.reviews;
        }
        if(data.user) {
            this.user().set(data.user, { parse: true });
            delete data.user;
        }
        if(data.image) {
            debugger
            this.image().set(data.image, { parse: true });
            delete data.image;
        }
        return data
    }

});
```

The parse function in the shop.js never even when I receive a shop in the listing.js parse function! `shop.image()` doesn't get set to an image model properly, so I have to call something wonky like `shop.get('image').url` to get the url.

Comment: Are you sure you implemented parse method correctly? And is the data OK? Please post your parse method body.

Comment: What do you mean by parse method body? I thought I did? The data seems correct in the listing.js parse method, but the debugger never even fires in the shop.js parse method.

Comment: I mean, maybe the problem is in malformed JSON

Comment: The JSON appears to be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the reason you're memoizing the image model in the shop is to maintain listeners and keep a single instance of that model around.

`Collection#set` takes a `parse` option that tells it to call parse on all the models that were set on the collection. `Model#set` is the method called immediately *after* calling parse using the attributes returned from `parse`.

In this case, we want to call `#set` on the associated `shop` model using the **parsed** attributes. So first lets call `parse`. It should look something like this:

```
SpendYourSavings.Models.Listing = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "api/listings",

    images: function() {
        this._images = this._images || new SpendYourSavings.Collections.Images([], { listing: this });
        return this._images;
    },

    reviews: function() {
        this._reviews = this._reviews || new SpendYourSavings.Collections.Reviews([], { listing: this });
        return this._reviews;
    },

    shop: function() {
        // Notice the first argument is an object when initializing models.
        this._shop = this._shop || new SpendYourSavings.Models.Shop({}, { listing: this });
        return this._shop;
    },

    parse: function(data) {
        if(data.images) {
            this.images().set(data.images, { parse: true });
            delete data.images;
        }
        if(data.reviews) {
            this.reviews().set(data.reviews, { parse: true });
            delete data.reviews;
        }
        if(data.shop) {
            var shopParams = this.shop().parse(data.shop);
            this.shop().set(shopParams);
            delete data.shop;
        }
        return data;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `parse: true` on `set` only really applies to collections.

These lines

```
this.images().set(data.images, { parse: true });
this.reviews().set(data.reviews, { parse: true });
```

work, because you are saying "add whole new models from this JSON".

This line

```
this.image().set(data.image, { parse: true });
```

however, is trying to say, parse these params, and set values, but that is weird on a model. Should it literally only parse the attributes that were passed in? Should it merge the attributes that the model already has? What if there were dependencies between the things already in the model and the things being parsed?

Instead, you might try restructuring your top-level parsing, e.g

```
SpendYourSavings.Models.Listing = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "api/listings/",
    images: function() {
        return this.get('images');
    },
    reviews: function() {
        return this.get('reviews');
    },
    shop: function() {
        return this.get('shop');
    },

    parse: function(data) {
        if (data.images){
            data.images = new SpendYourSavings.Collections.Images(data.images, { listing: this, parse: true});
        }
        if (data.reviews){
            data.reviews = new SpendYourSavings.Collections.Reviews(data.reviews, { listing: this, parse: true});
        }
        if (data.shop){
            data.shop = new SpendYourSavings.Models.Shop(data.shop, { listing: this, parse: true});
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```